# Do I need admin consent on Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a project in which I need to create events in my calendar, for this I am using the GRAPH API and there should be no user interaction. I'm using my personal account.

As a test I am making a call in Postman to which I add the token I got from the URL
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/events

{
  "subject": "My event",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-06-22T13:32:53.037Z",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-06-29T13:32:53.037Z",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error

```
{ "error": { "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken", "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.", "innerError": { "requestId": "b4ffb07b-8a7b-4893-93ae-1a3bb8be8f28", "date": "2020-06-23T03:14:49", "request-id": "b4ffb07b-8a7b-4893-93ae-1a3bb8be8f28" } } }
```

This is my token's body
[image]

---

These are the app permissions
[image]

Is this error because I don't have the admin consent or l'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your app in Azure AD?

Please follow steps described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Permission level you need is Calendar.ReadWrite

Comment: Yes, the only thing I'm missing is the admin consent because I'm using a personal Microsoft account

Comment: There's a way to insert events in calendar without user authentication?  (Using my personal account)